# Maxwell equations for waves propagation

Tags: equations

please how can we write this

[image]

and this

[image]

and thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up isn't clear. For all we know, you may not be looking for a TeX- or LaTeX-based solution. We also don't know if the arrow symbols above `B` and `E` truly are supposed to be displaced so horribly to the left. Please do show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
$\Delta\vec{E}-\epsilon_0\mu_0\frac{\partial^2\vec{E}}{\partial t^2}=0$
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: The code you show does not produce that output.

Comment: @campa Why not? The image was obtained with that code.

Comment: Because `\frac` used within `$...$` would give text a style fraction, while your image shows a display style fraction.